# how to access multiple controller without login in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symlink

*setting file*

```
enter code hereprod:
```

.settings:
    no_script_name:         true
    logging_enabled:        true

```
error_404_module:       error
error_404_action:       error404
```

dev:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false
all:
  .settings:
    i18n: true
    #default_culture: ru_RU

```
login_module:           login   # To be called when a non-authenticated user
login_action:          index  # Tries to access a secure page


secure_module: accessForbidden
secure_action: index




standard_helpers: [I18N,Partial,Text,app,menu,form]

# Form security secret (CSRF protection)
csrf_secret:            234sAFE425SDFAf2ljlkasdhfiwugb2563h2g4jA


# Output escaping settings
escaping_strategy:      false
escaping_method:        

# Enable the database manager
use_database:           true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable full access to all the pages on your site without requiring a session or making the user login, add this to your `apps/[YOUR_APP]/config/security.yml`:

```
default:
  is_secure: false
```

This will stop ALL controllers and actions from redirecting to a 404 page.

If you want to enable full access to just one module on your site without requiring a session or making the user login, add this to your `apps/[YOUR_APP]/modules/[YOUR MODULE]/config/security.yml`:

```
default:
  is_secure: false
```

This will disable security for just the actions in that one controller.

Comment: we are access some controller not all controller

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to do it for just some controllers.